# can someone tell me how would i modify this below script to delete the image from database after a click on cross?

Tags: php, ajax

can someone please tell me how would i modify this below script to delete the image from database after a click on cross?

```
<?php echo "<td>" ?>    
    <div class="image">
        <a href="delete.php?id='<?php $id; ?>'" onclick=" "><span class="close" name="delete_row" >&times;</span>
            <img width="100px" alt="" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" id="<?php $id; ?>">
        </a>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_to_be_deleted" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: select file name from database, using the id, which you passing, then @unlink('filename');

Comment: Thank you edCoder.. i do already have a code for that in another php file.

Comment: I will send you a part of the code to analyze what i want

Comment: you have to make an ajax post request to your other php file, call it in the onclick

Comment: can you send me the code for this?

Answer (score 0):

The image gets hidden after a click on cross. I have already built a code for that but it should also get deleted from my database which is a more challenging part i feel.

After refreshing the page the image is visible again as per the code. what extra things should be added to the code to also delete it from database.

So after refreshing the page the image is not visible again once it is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `unlink` function** like in your `delete.php` file

```
$sql=mysqli_query("select * from `products` where `id`='$_GET[id]'");
$r=mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
unlink("images/".$r->image);
```